# Payara5 - payaradomain on Java 9

Tags: java-9, payara

Im looking for some help running Payara 5 Alpha on Java 9. The blog post ["Payara Server 5 Alpha 2 release is here!"](http://blog.payara.fish/payara-server-5-alpha-2-release-is-here) says it runs the payara domain on Java 9, but Im still getting the java.lang.NullPointerException on AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator -

```
C:\payara-5.0.0.Alpha4-20171117.004238-21\payara5\bin>java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)


C:\payara-5.0.0.Alpha4-20171117.004238-21\payara5\bin>asadmin.bat start-domain payaradomain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:254)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
```

Is there more to the configuration? I've checked github for the Alpha2 and Alpha3 release but cant see more information relating to this

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Payara support for JDK 9 is still in the early stages and is not reliable. It is currently being worked on, but it will be complete by the time 5.181 is released. You can use GitHub (https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues) to report problems. You can also download the latest snapshot of Payara 5 from https://www.payara.fish/upstream_builds by scrolling down.

Comment: Thanks - but it does have early access Java 9 support on the payara domain - which im wanting to experiment with

Comment: If you download the latest snapshot (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/fish/payara/distributions/payara/5.0.0.Alpha4-SNAPSHOT/payara-5.0.0.Alpha4-20171207.004701-41.zip is today's build) and start payaradomain then Payara will start.

Comment: Tried it on windows - still getting exception as above

Comment: Please report it on Github then as that is a bug.